# Backbone Collection search through models attribute - done properly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have this nifty function that traverse through models in the collection for a attribute and value. If it finds the value it returns true.

After looking through a lot of doc's, I'm still a bit confused on how to traverse the 
collection properly and how to search through it.  Since underscorejs (in my case lodash) is hooked into backbone I do traverse the collection with .each

I didn't put an else after `if (model.get(attribute)===value)` because it would return false
before traversing through the whole collection. A callback function sounds like unnecessary complication - but maybe i'm wrong (I started with JS few months ago)

I'll be glad for tips and/or a nicer solution ;-) with an explonation.
Thanks in advance.

I use requirejs, that why I do pass the _,Bacbkone...

Here is how the Collection looks like:

```
function (_, Backbone, AppModels) {

    var QueriesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : AppModels.QueryModel,

        search: function (attribute, value) {
            var found = false;
            this.each(function (model) {
                if (model.get(attribute)===value) {
                    found = true;
                }
            });
            return found;
        }
    });

    return {
        QueriesCollection: QueriesCollection
    };
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also use the Underscore [`some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some) (aka `any`), which is almost the same as your `search` function, except it takes a function argument to use as its predicate, instead of a key/value:

> Returns true if any of the values in the list pass the iterator truth test. Short-circuits and stops traversing the list if a true element is found.

The implementation use this is a bit more direct:

```
search: function (attribute, value) {
    return this.some(function(x) { 
        return x.get(attribute) === value; 
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you @dbaseman - looks like a more elegant solution. does backbone collections inherit all of the underscore methods _directly_ (accesible through collection. dot notation)? i heave to read the doc's better ;)

Comment: They do, yes -- see this part in the Backbone docs, where it notes that Backbone collections proxy to all the Underscore methods:  http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods